# Scrollbar misalignment: HTML Table with fixed headers, scrollable tbody and fluid column width

Tags: css, scrollbar, fixed-header-tables

I would like to use pure CSS to make a HTML Table with fixed headers, scrollable tbody and fluid column width.

I made the `thead` and `tbody` `display: block` and added fixed column width to `th` and `td` except for the first column which needs to occupy the full available width.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) { width: 100%; }
  td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) { min-width: 100px; }
  td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) { min-width: 100px; }

  thead {
    display: block;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

All is working well except for the scrollbar misalignment issue. The scrollbar pushes the content to the left by certain pixels which is not fixed across browsers.

I wonder if it can be solved with some CSS tweaks?

This is the full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqVOON/

Comment: Will this works https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbwbYX

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But 17px is not cross browser. For example, on Ubuntu, chrome has 15px width scrollbar and FF has 10px

Comment: then you have to use javascript  to detect scrollbar width  and change margin values